# Use of default trustStore with SSL connection

Tags: spring-amqp

When using SSL, `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` requires both `keyStore` and `trustStore` to be explicitly specified in the SSL properties. I'm looking for a way to work around this requirement when the server uses a well-known CA present in the default `trustStore`, since manually maintaining a separate JKS for this purpose becomes quite tedious.

Note: The Javadoc is clear on what needs to be overridden in order to modify the default behavior. However, I'm also using the Spring Boot autoconfiguration which is [hardwired](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration.java#L92) to use the default implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is too restrictive. I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-649).

In the meantime, you can simply wire up your own

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties config)
```

to override the default boot one; you'll still get the remaining boot autoconfig stuff.